# Limit charging file

Tags: android

I want to write code that will disable battery charge when reaching 80% and enable when gets to 20%, should work on LG K4 5.0.

I have been looking around and tested a lot of solutions but none of them work.

Changing `sys/devices/platform/battery/power_supply/ac/online` to `0` or
`sys/devices/platform/battery/power_supply/ac/present` to `0`,
cause android to crash and reboot.

I have found a file called `LGBM_AtCmdChargingModeOff` when changed to `1` it stops charging but can't change it back to 0, after reboot, it's `0` again.

Any idea on how to change this file back to 0 without a reboot? 
`cat` doesn't work.
`vi` doesn't work.
paste with value = 1 doesn't work.

Comment: Each manufacturer could have different method to do that. Moreover some manufacturers could have disabled this kind of possibility. However try to go to "/sys/class/power_supply/battery folder", open the charging_enabled file with a text editor, delete the number 1, and then replace it with the number 0. When you're done there, save the file. A restart will set the value back to 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have charging_enabled file inside /sys/class/power_supply/battery folder

Answer (score 1):

Just use Chargie (google for "chargie stick"). It's a Bluetooth charge limiter that does exactly what you want (hysteretic charging).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This answer doesn't really answer the question; OP was asking for _code_ to create the effect they were looking for, not hardware recommendations. If you know of way to answer the question using the methods they asked for, please edit your answer to include that info.